# Can't update an entity with Poco Code Generation Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, poco

I have the following scenario:

the below 2 global variables in my page:

```
MainContext db = new MainContext();
User user = new User();
```

A method to fill the properties that is called on the button update:

```
private void FillProperties()
        {
            user.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
            user.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
            user.Email = txtEmail.Text;
        }
```

on the button update i am doing the following:

```
FillProperties();
user.ID = Request.QueryString("userid");
db.SaveChanges();
```

but the record isn't been updated which i think is logical since the user variable isn't related to db object, but i a, not being able to do this:

```
db.Users.AddObject(user);
```

since AddObject isn't found in the db properties.

What can I do to update user?

Your answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) API simply use

```
db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: @Eranga i believe that the scheme might be malformed (eg missing PK/AI, differences between serialized scheme and actual scheme)

Comment: now this is what i call a straight forward answer and to the point. thank you sooo much :)

Answer (score 0):

Where do you add your user to the DB?
If the user exists in the DB, in order to update it, you should do, for example:

```
user = db.Users.Where(x => x.ID == Request.QueryString("userid")).Single();
FillProperties();
db.SaveChanges();
```